# Implementing your own depth buffer with GLSL

Tags: shader, glsl, depth

I need a datastructure of the same size as the normal depth buffer and I need to be able to read from and write to it in a shader. Is this possible, and what does this datastructure look like?

Answer (score 2):

No, a GLSL shader cannot read and write the same buffer.

In a nutshell, parallelising the shader work would not be simple otherwise.